# Send Variables POST and GET

Tags: php, post, get

How can I request a URL with my own variables without using it through a HTML form?

Thanks!

EDIT:

When a specific page loads I want to send a request to a url with a couple of my own variables.

Ex: I come to www.example.com/done
the page sends a request to www.example2.com?abc=123&def=456

Comment: Remember, we have no context about what you're asking. Please revise your question for someone who has no idea what you are doing.

Comment: First, please post what you've tried already. We can't write code for you, and there's no point giving you code you've already tried. Also, as for the requesting of a second page on loading, look into `cURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` variables are either sent through a form (hence, `POST`ing them), or sent using `AJAX`.

`GET`variables, however, are simply passed through the URL. For instance, if you wanted to send `foo=bar` to `example2.php`, you could use

```
<a href="example2.php?foo=bar">Go to example2.php</a>
```

And then in `example2.php`, you could say

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
```

Simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad, but there is an answer...

By issuing HTTP request in a different way, for example:

- by calling it using AJAX from some website (eg. [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)),
- by issuing a request using some kind of tool, like browser extension (eg. [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) for Google Chrome),
- by using some library to do such call in an automated way (eg. [Requests library for Python](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)),

In general, `GET` parameters are passed in the URL, while `POST` parameters are passed in the body, so to pass both, you need to do both, by issuing `POST` request and:

- appending `GET` parameters to the URL, in URL-encoded way (like "`...?par1=1&par2=2`"),
- passing `POST` parameters in the body of the request, also URL-encoded

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX in javascript. For a beginner I'd recommend using the jQuery library

```
$.get("url", {key: "value"}, function(resp) {})
```

or

```
$.post("url", {key: "value"}, function(resp) {})
```

Should suffice

Comment: Do you have any examples you could give me regarding the AJAX? never used it before :/

Comment: I've edited it to include examples of POST and GET. Note that the request must be of the same domain as the site running the javascript.